# How to display a tag for each link which is in for loop using jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a div  with an id of 'b1' inside a for loop.This div is clickable and when I click on this link, I would like to display tags related to that div to appear below that particular div b1.But as per my code, it just displays the tags for the first div.Below is my code

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b1").click(function(){
      $('#newdiv').slideToggle();  
        $id= $(this).attr('data-target');
        $src =  $('#newdiv'); 
        $idTrg = $('#'+$id);
        $src.html($idTrg.html());

    });
});
        </script>

       <style>
#newdiv{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:orange;
}
/*#newdiv:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}*/
</style> 
    </head>
<body>
   <?php for($i=1;$i<9; $i++): ?>
           <div id="whole">
<div id="b1" data-target="<?php  echo $i; ?>">Content<?php  echo $i; ?></div>
<div id="newdiv"  style="display:none" ></div>
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>

   <?php for($j=1;$j<9; $j++): ?>
<div id="<?php echo $j ;?>" style="display:none">
    Main contents<?php echo $j; ?>
    <div id="another">Inside Another one<?php echo $j; ?></div>
</div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</body>
```

How can I get each div contents to appear below it on  clicking the link?Could somebody help me with this jquery

Comment: the tags are for "whole" or "newdiv"  ??

Comment: For 'newdiv'.'newdiv' is a div inside 'whole' which has a style of display none and gets displayed only when the respective 'b1' div is clicked on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to validate your generated HTML (http://validator.w3.org/). You can't have a `script` element inside another.

IDs have to be unique in HTML documents and jQuery has a "fix" built in, so that selecting an ID will allways only return one element. By having the `div` inside the loop it's output multiple times in the resulting HTML code (look at the generated source in the browser).

You have to replace the ID with a class.

Furthermore `$('#newdiv')` (or `$('.newdiv')` if using a class) will select any/all element with that ID/class, not the one specifically the one beside the clicked element. You could use `.next()` to find it instead.

Finally some general code style advice:

- Use better ID/class names. `b1` doesn't mean anything. And you swapped the meaning of "source" and "target".
- Declare all variables with `var` otherwise they will be global variables.
- Don't prefix all your variables with `$`. Some people use the `$` prefix for variables holding jQuery objects, which is ok (but not recommended), but it certainly doesn't make sense for other variables.
- Indent your code more cleanly, so that it's better readable.

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".b1").click(function(){
        var $target = $(this).next();
        $target.slideToggle();  
        var id = $(this).attr('data-target');
        $src = $('#'+id);
        $target.html($src.html());
      });
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    .newdiv{
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:orange;
    }
  </style> 
</head>
<body>
  <?php for($i=1;$i<9; $i++): ?>
    <div class="whole">
      <div class="b1" data-target="<?php  echo $i; ?>">Content<?php  echo $i; ?></div>
      <div class="newdiv"  style="display:none" ></div>
    </div>
  <?php endfor; ?>

  <?php for($j=1;$j<9; $j++): ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $j ;?>" style="display:none">
      Main contents<?php echo $j; ?>
      <div class="another">Inside Another one<?php echo $j; ?></div>
    </div>
  <?php endfor; ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, that worked really well.And thanks for explaining it too.I am new to jquery and just did a quick code to see the output, tats why the id and class names are crap but I understand standard names help understand the code better.Thanks for the help!